# Convert Carrage returns to br tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, jquery-plugins

I'm stuck with a small problem of parsing carrage return in a text area.

JQuery Code

```
$.fn.escapeHtml = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).html(
            $(this).html()
                .replace(/"/g,"&quot;")
                .replace(/&/g,'&amp;')
                .replace(/</g,'&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
                .replace(/'/g,'&apos;')
                // For converting carrage return (enter key) to br
                .replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '&lt; br &gt;')
                .replace(/183/g,'&middot;')
        );
    });
    return $(this);
}
})(jQuery);
```

In Firefox it works and gives the output as

```
&lt;big&gt;Heading&lt;/big&gt;<br>Test Line 1<br>Test Line 2<br>Test Line 3
```

In Internet Explorer it doesnt work at all.. How do i fix this in IE. My intented output is like this

```
&lt;big&gt;Heading&lt;/big&gt;&lt;br&gt;Test Line 1&lt;br&gt;Test Line 2&lt;br&gt;Test Line 3
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '&lt; br &gt;')
```

With:

```
.replace(/(\n\n|\r|\n)/g, '&lt; br &gt;')
```

Note also that in textarea, both of them boil down to `\n` so you need to replace with two of them eg `\n\n`.